# Need help getting a function to function

Tags: functions, errors

I am writing my first function in the functions.php file in my child theme and am running into problems getting it to work. I keep getting an error that seems to be syntax related, like WP doesn't want to see "var". I am also not clear how to run the function either, being a very basic programmer.

Here is the code I got working in JSfiddle that I am trying to use in WP:

```
function adjustLogoHeight() {

var divHeight = $('#et-top-navigation').height();

 $('.logo_container').css('height', divHeight+'px');

};

adjustLogoHeight();
```

If you have a solution that I can try, I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi there! Would it be possible to see the exact error message? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your code is based on **jQuery** and you are including it to a **PHP** file. So you need to call it between `<script></script>` tag and obviously either you must end and start PHP tags before `<script>` and after `</script>` or echo the full script.

Now come to how you are gonna execute the code. You can hook the `adjustLogoHeight()` function to any hook which fires on where you need to put the function-

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'adjustLogoHeight' );
```

Or you can direct call the function where you want to put the function by calling the function like `adjustLogoHeight()`.

Now a little update on your jQuery code-

```
function adjustLogoHeight() { ?>
    <script>
        (function( $ ) {
            'use strict';
            var divHeight = $('#et-top-navigation').height();
            $('.logo_container').css('height', divHeight+'px');
        })( jQuery );
    </script>
<?php };
```

Write your function like above. It's more appropriate.

> Must call the `adjustLogoHeight` function after **jQuery** is loaded to the DOM. Otherwise you'll get error whether you're calling it directly or hooking it to any hook.